# Processing Arduino Communication Comparison

Tags: serialization, arduino, processing

My Processing code succesfully print the string data sent from the Arduino, however I cannot do a comparison using IF/ELSE. For example, on console it prints "ic" however it doesnt run the if value == "ic" code. Appreciate all the helps.

```java
import processing.serial.*;

PImage k;  // Declare variable "a" of type PImage
PImage y;
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val; 

void setup() {
  size(1300, 800);
  // The image file must be in the data folder of the current sketch 
  // to load successfully
  k = loadImage("k_ray.png");  // Load the image into the program  
  y = loadImage("y_ray.png");
  String portName = Serial.list()[1]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {
  val = myPort.readString();
  println(val);

    if (val == "ic"){
    println("hop");
    image(y, 398, 600);
  }
  else if(val == "ig"){
    println("hop");
    image(k, 398, 600);
  }
  }



}
```

So it only outputs "ic" and "ig" but doesnt output "hop".

Here is the Arduino code aswell:

```java
int icount=0;
int rcount=0;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


int bc = analogRead(A2);
int bg = analogRead(A3);
int rc = analogRead(A4);
int ic = analogRead(A5);
int ig = analogRead(A1);
if (ic < 100){
  icount=icount-1;
  rcount=rcount+1;
  Serial.println("ic");
}
if (ig < 100){
  icount=icount+1;
  Serial.println("ig");
}
}
```

Comment: `"ic"` is not the same as `"ic\r\n"` or `"ic\r\nic\r\nic\r\nic\r\nic\r\nig\r\nig\r\nic\r\nic\r\n"`.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Take Kevin's advice and also [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) the string to remove the return and new line characters

Answer (score 0):

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/String.html):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the `equals()` method, as in `if (a.equals(b))`, instead of `if (a == b)`. A String is an Object, so comparing them with the == operator only compares whether both Strings are stored in the same memory location. Using the `equals()` method will ensure that the actual contents are compared. (The [troubleshooting](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Troubleshooting#Why_don.27t_these_Strings_equal.3F) reference has a longer explanation.)

In other words, you shouldn't do this:

```
if (val == "ic"){
```

Instead, you should do this:

```
if (val.equals("ic")){
```

Taking a step back, you should get into the habit of [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to figure out what's going on. Try to narrow your problem down to a single line that's behaving differently from what you expected, and it'll be much easier to figure out problems like this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer but unfortunately it still doenst work :(

Comment: @OnurSertgil Can you please be more specific than saying it doesn't work? Have you tried debugging? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: Yes, I checked the debugging guide you have sent. It doesnt run the code in the if statements althought the if statment cases are true.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value? What values are going into the `if` statement? Can you isolate it to a simple [mcve] that demonstrates just the `if` statement, using hard-coded values?